# Hourly and daily groups with overlapping days (11:00 pm-1:00am)

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, datepart

I'm attempting to count number of ids active during a given hourly window and day. I have three columns: start_time, end_time, and id.

Most of the groups are standard same-day groupings, i.e., 9am-11am, 11am-1pm, etc.

One of the groupings overlaps two days (11pm-1am). That is, May 16 11:01 PM and May 17 12:01 AM should be in the same group. But when composing a simple query, you'd end up grouping May 17 12:01 AM within the May 17 11:00pm.

I've tried several queries with several variations of case statements and subqueries, but can't get the gist.

This below query attempt gives me 0 for 11pm_1am column. I figured I could just move a 12:30 AM time into the previous date and count it there, but no luck.

```sql
select date_trunc('day', start_time_1) as date_active
, count(distinct(case when CAST(start_time_1 AS TIME) <= '06:00:00' and CAST(end_time_1 AS TIME) >= '01:00:00' then id end)) as early_morning
, count(distinct(case when CAST(start_time_1 AS TIME) <= '00:00:00' and CAST(end_time_1 AS TIME) >= '23:00:00' then id end)) as overnight_11pm_1am
from 
(select id
, case 
when cast(start_time as time) between '00:00:00' and '01:00:00' 
then start_time - INTERVAL '01:00' HOUR TO MINUTE 
else start_time 
end as start_time_1
,case 
when cast(end_timeas time) between '00:00:00' and '01:00:00' 
then end_time - INTERVAL '01:00' HOUR TO MINUTE 
else end_time 
end as end_time_1
from table
where start_time >= '2021-01-01'
and  start_time < '2021-01-04'
)
group by date_active
```

Out of ideas.

Comment: Maybe first create a CASE that puts each row in one of the three buckets. Then use date and the new bucket field to perform you grouping.

Comment: Could you post an example input and the expected output?

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Those are two very different databases

Comment: I think that you should split your overlapping group into 2 groups - 1 hour for the previous day and 1 hour for the next day. Without splitting, the group can be only attached to one of the 2 adjacent days.